# How to add user to AzureDevOps programmatically (e.g. Rest API) without notification?

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to add users to my Azure DevOps Services Organization programatically without them getting notifications. I've started with a script like below using the [User Entitlement Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/enus/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) but users still get notifications:

```js
$method = 'POST'
$devopsuri = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/<Devops org name>/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
$pat = "<pat>"
$encodedPat = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$pat"))
$header = @ {
  Authorization = "Basic $encodedPat"
}
$body = @ {
  "accessLevel" = @ {
    "accountLicenseType" = "stakeholder"
  }
  "user" = @ {
    "principalName" = "<UPN>"
    "subjectKind" = "user"
  }
} | ConvertTo - Json - Depth 5
$result = Invoke - RestMethod - Uri $devopsuri - Method $method - Headers $header - Body $body - UseBasicParsing - ContentType 'application/json'
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we don’t check `Send email invites` in UI, invitees will not receive notification.
So we can grab this api by pressing `f12` in the browser.

[image]

[image]

**Rest api**: need to add `doNotSendInviteForNewUsers=true` to the url and use `PATCH` method.

```
PATCH https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/UserEntitlements?doNotSendInviteForNewUsers=true&api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

**Sample request body**:

```
[{"from":"","op":0,"path":"","value":{"accessLevel":{"licensingSource":1,"accountLicenseType":2,"msdnLicenseType":0,"licenseDisplayName":"Basic","status":0,"statusMessage":"","assignmentSource":1},"user":{"principalName":"XXXX@outlook.com","subjectKind":"user"}}}]
```

My test in Postman:

[image]